# Sails.js API documentation

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, sails.js, swagger

I want to develop an API using the MVC pattern. I found sails framework interesting and I'd like to know if it's possible to configure swagger or something like with sails to generate the documentation of my API (something like swagger-express for express for example).

Thanks!

Comment: You could try doing it yourself, swagger only needs and endpoint from where to read all the information about server endpoints or maybe in the spec https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec

Comment: I guess I have to try to do so, it doesn't look that someone has worked on a solution yet.

Comment: We're working on it.

Comment: **sails-hook-swagger-generator** library should help in performing that witth little or no configuration https://github.com/theo4u/sails-hook-swagger-generator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did to have my documentation work with sails.js : you can download swagger-ui here : https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui or via npm (npm install swagger-ui).

Then in the assets folder of your sails project, create a folder that points to the swagger folder ("docs" for example, so you'll be able to access to your documentation via your_url:port/docs)

Answer (score 5):

This feature is in progress. If you'd like to help out, we can all collaborate here: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1094

#### Update (August 2015):

Check out this Sails Hook that offers native Swagger integration. It compiles all of the bound routes in Sails, and generates a Swagger 2.0 document: https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-swagger

Comment: Did you make any progress in getting info on how to implement something like this with sails express app?

Comment: When i use sails-swagger it says :- error: The bootstrap function threw an error after its callback was called :: Ty
peError: Cannot set property 'doc' of undefined

Do you have any documentation about how to implement